# Unable to modify class variable from within new function

Tags: c++, class, variables, ncurses

I'm still relatively new to C++ and programming, but having a good time learning. I'm writing a small, very simple ncurses program that so far should simply move a "#" around the screen using the WASD keys.

The problem is I am unable to change player.x in the first function Update().

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
    public:

    int x;
    int y;
};

void Update()
{
    int z;

    z = getch();

    if(z == 97) //A key
        {
            player.x--;
        }

    if(z == 100) //D key
        {
            player.x++;         
        }   

    if(z == 119) //W key
        {
            player.y--;
        }

    if(z == 115) //S key
        {
            player.y++;         
        }   
}


void Draw(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    clear();

    mvprintw(yPos,xPos,"#");

    refresh();
}

int main()
{
    initscr();
    noecho();

    int doContinue;

    Player player;

    do
    {           
        Update();       
        Draw(player.x, player.y);

    }while((doContinue=getch()) != 27);

    endwin();   
    return 0;
}
```

Any input would be helpful!

Comment: What do you mean you are "unable" to change `player.x`? Does it give you a compile-time error? Does it do nothing at runtime? Have you tried added debug prints?

Comment: You may want to check for the screen border so that you don't draw outside of the screen.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan I forgot to specify the compiler was complaining player.x was not defined in this scope. Also hochl I'll be doing that after ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables in c++ are associated with a scope.  Think of scope as the visibility of that variable.  In this case player is only visible with in the function it is declared in which is main.  To update player you must either increase its scope and make it global (bad idea) or b. pass it into you function.

If your changed your `Update` to take a player reference you could accomplish what you attempted.  The new declaration would look like this 'void Update(Player &player)` then when you call your update function pass in the instance

Comment: This is awesome, thanks to all who gave this solution! I got it working, and now much better understand classes!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `player` declared in `Update()`.  In order to have this working, you need to be able to access the `player` variable declared in `main`.  To do that you need to pass the variable by pointer or reference to `Update`.

In main:

```
Update(player);
```

Change the signature of Update to:

```
void Update(Player& player);
```

This passes the object named `player` of type `Player` to `Update` by reference.

Answer (score 0):

How is the `Update` function supposed to know what object it's supposed to modify? You create a `Player` called `player`, but then you don't give that to the `Update` function.